# Metropolis-Hasting algorithm for spanning tree

Tags: algorithms

How to give a set of transitions sufficient to transform any spanning tree into any another spanning tree in a finite number of steps via spanning trees using Metropolis-Hasting ratio? I was wondering if someone can help me?

In this context, transition means adding one edge and removing another. Then we add an edge that we need and then just we remove an edge from the formed cycle that we don't need. This will work in at most n−1 steps. My confusion is how it is explained with Metropolis-Hasting ratio.